# Stream screen:// over chromecast

Tags: vlc-media-player, chromecast

I'm trying to cast `screen://` to the chrome cast device.

The best result I've got by calling:
`cvlc screen:// --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=none}:chromecast' --sout-chromecast-ip=192.168.1.138`, but it takes ages to connect and display just one frame.

Where might be the issue?